# Remove checkbox php

Tags: php, html, checkbox, web

I'm really new to PHP, and i'm currently making a small webshop (Locally) to try out my skills.

I've got some code, where there is a checkbox if you are a danish citizen, but i want the checkbox to be removed and then just run the code which normally only would have been running if it was checked no matter what.

Can you guys give me a hint or direction i should go?

```
function my_pmpro_tax($tax, $values, $order) {      

    $tax = round((float)$values[price]*0.8 * 0.25, 2);      
    return $tax;  

}

function my_pmpro_level_cost_text($cost, $level)
{
    //only applicable for levels > 1
    $cost .= "Inkl. moms";

    return $cost;
}

add_filter("pmpro_level_cost_text", "my_pmpro_level_cost_text", 10, 2);
//add Danish checkbox to the checkout page
function my_pmpro_checkout_boxes()
{
?>

<table id="pmpro_pricing_fields" class="pmpro_checkout" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Do you live in Denmark?
        </th>                       
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <div>               
                <input id="danish" name="danish" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if(!empty($_REQUEST['danish']) || !empty($_SESSION['danish'])) {?>checked="checked"<?php } ?> /> Check this box if your billing address is in Denmark.
            </div>              
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
}

add_action("pmpro_checkout_boxes", "my_pmpro_checkout_boxes");
//update tax calculation if buyer is danish
function my_danish_tax_check()
{
    //check request and session
    if(isset($_REQUEST['danish']))
    {
        //update the session var
        $_SESSION['danish'] = $_REQUEST['danish'];  

        //not empty? setup the tax function
        if(!empty($_REQUEST['danish']))
            add_filter("pmpro_tax", "my_pmpro_tax", 10, 3);
    }
    elseif(!empty($_SESSION['danish']))
    {
        //add the filter
        add_filter("pmpro_tax", "my_pmpro_tax", 10, 3);
    }
}

add_action("init", "my_danish_tax_check");
//remove the danish session var on checkout
function my_pmpro_after_checkout()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['danish']))
        unset($_SESSION['danish']);
}

add_action("pmpro_after_checkout", "my_pmpro_after_checkout");
```

Comment: You can do those from your client side i.e., jquery

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `function my_danish_tax_check()` so it looks like this:

```
function my_danish_tax_check()
{
        //update the session var
        $_SESSION['danish'] = 1;  

        add_filter("pmpro_tax", "my_pmpro_tax", 10, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this look bizarre:

```
<?php if(!empty($_REQUEST['danish']) || !empty($_SESSION['danish'])) {?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>
```

More accurately:

```
<?php if(!empty($_REQUEST['danish']) || !empty($_SESSION['danish'])) { echo "checked="checked"" } ?>
```

For your problem we need to now server side codes of target page after that page. You should share that information with us.

If you are talking about passing this page just make a redirection:

```
function Redirect()
{
    window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the code for if (not danish citizen) part !